# How to use javascript to store variables to window correctly?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I am trying to use JSNI (gwt's javacript interface) to set/get variable to/from js object:window like this:

```
private final native <T> T get(String key)/*-{
    return $wnd.key;
}-*/;


private final native void set(String key, Object value)/*-{
    $wnd.key = value;
}-*/;
```

///// js equivalent should like this

```
function get(String key){
    return window.key;
}


function set(String key, var value){
    window.key = value;
}
```

and if I set a variable: var_1 to window:

```
var var_1={"id":"id_1","name":"name_1"} 
set("key_1",var_1)
```

then

```
get("key_1")
```

I will get var_1 correctly

and then set another variable var_2 to window

```
var var_2={"id":"id_2","name":"name_2"} 
set("key_2",var_2)
```

then,try to get key_1 again

```
get("key_1")
```

unexpectedly,var_2 will be returned

so,the problem is obvious:the get() function will always return the last set variable no matter what key is.Questions are:

```
1,Why?
2,How to make it right?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Changing to

```
private final native <T> T get(String key)/*-{
    return $wnd[key];
}-*/;


private final native void set(String key, Object value)/*-{
    $wnd[key] = value;
}-*/;
```

Both set and get work as expected now.

Comment: Seems like you demonstrated that in JS the dot notation refinement is always literal, whereas refinement via "[]" operator results in variable resolution. I didn't know this fine detail of the language - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deal with JSNI for this, you already have some useful methods in the `Element` class, so just cast the object `Window` to an element and that is.

This code should work:

```java
Element window = ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW.cast();

window.setPropertyJSO("key_jso", JsArray.createArray()); 
JavaScriptObject jso = window.getPropertyJSO("key_jso")

window.setPropertyBoolean("key_boolean", true); 
boolean b = window.getPropertyBoolean("key_boolean")

// and the same with:
// setPropertyDouble, getPropertyDouble
// setPropertyInt, getPropertyInt
// setPropertyString, getPropertyString
// setPropertyObject, getPropertyObject
```

If you are using [gwtquery](http://gwtquery.org), a library I recomend to always import in any gwt project, you can simply do:

```java
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.*;

$(window).prop("key", value);
boolean b = $(window).prop("key");
// or
boolean b = $(window).prop("key", Boolean.class);
// And the same with any type (JavaScriptObject, Double, Integer ...)
```